# Landing Page Not Loading - Selenium Web Form Automation

Tags: python, selenium, css-selectors, webdriverwait, firefox-profile

Creating a script that will log in into the site below and automatically log values into a web form. The problem is that once I login, the landing page is blank (i.e it loads headers but that's it). My code is below:

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.accept_untrusted_certs = True
browser = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
browser.get('https://cmsdb.darkcosmos.org/experiments/run/new')
print('Connected to Server')
time.sleep(2) # Wait for page to load
login_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[5]/main/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/button')
login_button.click()
time.sleep(2) # Wait for pop-out to load
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="username"]').send_keys(username)
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]').send_keys(password)
login_attempt = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div/form/button[1]')
login_attempt.submit()
print('Logged In')
time.sleep(2) # Wait for new page to load
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="title"]').send_keys('Title') #  Code breaks here. It cannot find the title entry area because the new page is blank.
```

I've tried making a Firefox profile, giving the page time to load, and turning certificates off. It loads just fine when I manual login. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Did you try login_attempt.click() instead of login_attempt.submit()?

Answer (score 0):

To login within the url `https://cmsdb.darkcosmos.org/experiments/run/new` and provide the **username** and **password** using a new **FirefoxProfile** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *elements to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
  profile.accept_untrusted_certs = True
  browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
  browser.get('https://cmsdb.darkcosmos.org/experiments/run/new')
  print('Connected to Server')
  login_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[5]/main/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/button')
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.v-content__wrap button.v-btn.v-btn--flat.theme--light.primary--text"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#username"))).send_keys("clcarver")
  browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input#password").send_keys("clcarver")
  login_attempt = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("div.v-btn__content>i.v-icon.pr-1.mdi.mdi-lock-open-outline.theme--light").click()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Connected to Server
  ```
- Browser Screenshot:

[image: DarkCosmos_Login]